# Why media has changed to 'screen'?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, amazon-cloudfront

My app has been deployed to the cloud for few months, and there were no problem with the CSS at all.

All assets are served using CloudFront, after I have added the staging server url as another origin to my distribution at CloudFront, I've noticed that when opening my app at the production server, a `media="screen"` is overriding `media="all"`, thus changing the final look!

What I need to know, is how `media="screen"` was added to my served pages? I didn't touch the production server.

I only used my PC to view the app, not a phone or tablet..

Any explanation?

Comment: are you using any css pre-processors? If you are serving a static file, there's nothing that could change it - look out for minimization settings on CloudFront.

Comment: You are lacking in details. :)
However: files don't change themselves nor does CloudFront, are you using any cms? And how do you build your page, do you have an html template or it's built by software?

Comment: Its a rails app, a ruby based framework, compiled assets are copied to public folder, which is deployed within the app directory to the server, could the CloudFront process the served css files? they should be served as is, right?

Comment: In my rails app I use Sass as a css pre-processor, but once the css file is compiled and deployed, it should not get changed, as I understand..

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it is overriding the media query, because you are using it form your PC. Are you going to visualize your app on all the different media types?

Comment: No, I am targeting big display, like PC